# Highlight Active Button in Yosemite

Tags: keyboard, macos

I usually work without using the mouse too much. 
In Mavericks the active button (the one that's pressed using the spacebar) had a nice blue outline. Any way to get that back?

In the screenshot below "Don't Save" is actually active and pressing space presses it. also Tab-Space presses the cancel button.

[image: Screenshot]

Old UI:

[image]

Comment: On Mavericks it was in `Preferences` -> `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts` -> `All Controls` (Toggled with `CTRL` + `F7`). I don't have Yosemite right now so I can't check it.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek That only toggles the setting - yosemite doesn't actually highlight the button, even with that toggle on.

Answer (score 1):

This used to work in every application for me until I installed Yosemite. Now, It only works for certain applications. The way around this is to use the 'command + (first letter of the button text)'  For example, if you want to choose "Don't Save" then 'command+d'.

Comment: Thanks rod, but indeed I explicitly asking for a way to get the outline back. That's why Tetsujin started this comment with "Not an answer" above...

Answer (score 0):

This works in Yosemite (10.10.3), not sure about earlier versions:

1. First make sure that you have a highlight colour set in System Preferences > General: [image: General Preferences with 'Highlight Color' circled in red]
2. In System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts, review the setting that lets you toggle how Tab moves focus. This lets you change the setting in #3 below by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. I leave mine off because I always want tab to move between all controls and don't want to change this by a keyboard shortcut.
3. Make sure the 'All controls' setting is selected so that you can tab between all the controls (including the Save/Don't Save buttons).
   [image: Keyboard shortcuts preferences with tab focus settings circled in red]

Now you can tab between all controls and see the highlight for the active control (shown with red lines in image below). For some control types (such as the segmented control at the top) once you've selected it with tab, you choose the active segment using the cursor keys (shown by blue arrow in image below).

[image: About This Mac window, with 'Overview' segment selected and tab-path drawn on in red, cursor-keys path shown by an arrow in blue.]

Comment: This doesn't work.